# Troubles with makefiles

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc, makefile

I have 4 components:

- MainA
- MainB
- ImplA
- ImplB

My executables should be `Bin1` and `Bin2` - `MainA`and `MainB` use `ImplA` and `ImplB`, respectively. My makefile is:

```
CC=g++
CCOPTS=-g -w

OBJS = $(BINDIR)/MainA.o $(BINDIR)/MainB.o $(BINDIR)/ImplA.o $(BINDIR)/ImplB.o 
TARGETS = $(BINDIR)/Bin1 $(BINDIR)/Bin2
BINDIR = build

all: $(TARGETS) $(OBJS)

clean:
    rm -f $(TARGETS) $(OBJS)

.PHONY: all clean

$(BINDIR)/Bin1 : $(BINDIR)/MainA.o $(BINDIR)/ImplA.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

$(BINDIR)/Bin2 : $(BINDIR)/MainB.o $(BINDIR)/ImplB.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

$(BINDIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) -c $(CCOPTS) -o $@ $<
```

When I attempt to make, I get:

```
g++ -c -g -w -o build/MainA.o MainA.cpp
Assembler messages:
Fatal error: can't create build/MainA.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [build/MainA.o] Error 1
```

What don't I understand?

Comment: Does `MainA.cpp` exist and does the name exactly match (case sensitive)?

Comment: Yes, they are all in the same folder, with names matched exactly

Comment: Also, can you use `$(BINDIR)` **before** you actually define it with `BINDIR=build`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the directory `build` doesn't exist.

Comment: You can always change your makefile to create it... but you'll have to do it either by hand or in the makefile.  Make won't create it for you.